# How can I improve the readibility of this

Tags: css

I have got a table with white font on a blue background as you can see its not the easiest to read. is there any font/solution to make it a bit more eye friendly with css. im using ie6

(the info displayed is made up)

edit: I cant change the background image and colour because theyre the companies colours

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could give the tablecells a solid black background, and then make it slightly transparent.

```
td { 
   /* Fallback for web browsers that doesn't support RGBa */
   background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  /* RGBa with 0.6 opacity */
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}
```

(css is from http://robertnyman.com/2010/01/11/css-background-transparency-without-affecting-child-elements-through-rgba-and-filters/ , look there if you want to make it compatible with MSIE)

Comment: those exmaples didnt work for IE6. I found this however. opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50); it works but when i put it in a td it changes the occupicy. how can i make it change a background of the td?

Comment: As I said, it doesn't work with IE. Follow the link for the complete explanation, and fix for msie.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I think it looks fine, but to others it might be harder to read. What I'd do is give it a flat, untextured background, like you have in the image on the right hand column. You could possibly make the contrast a bit better by darkening the background. The only small issue I can find with your image is the textured background to the left.